# solve following system of non-linear differential equations: $x'=3x -x^2+\frac{1}{2}xy$ and $y'=\frac{1}{5}xy-y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

---

I m trying to solve the following system of non-linear differential equations:
$\begin{cases} x'=3x -x^2+\frac{1}{2}xy \\ y'=\frac{1}{5}xy-y \end{cases}$

**what I have tried so far**

I have first tried to solve the equations by:
$$\frac{dx/dt}{dy/dt}=\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{(3-x+\frac{1}{2}y)x}{(\frac{1}{5}x-1)y}$$
$$\iff \frac{(\frac{1}{5}x-1)\cdot dx }{x}=\frac{(3-x+\frac{1}{2}y)\cdot dy}{y}$$

now I could integrate the left side of the equation, but I m still stuck with the right side.
Could somebody help me solving this system of ODE?
unfortunately I haven't found any answer which would point me to the right direction, if there is one, I didn't see the connection just jet and I would appreciate a reference and perhaps a small explanation how to apply it to my specific problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't put multiline formulas in the title. It messes up some list displays in the site.

Comment: Notice that the second equation lets us express $y$ in terms of $x$ via integration:
$$y(t) = C \exp \left(-t + \frac15 \int^t x(\tau)\,d\tau\right) ,$$ so the system is equivalent to a single nonlinear, second-order differential equation in $X(t) := \int^t x(\tau) \,d\tau$, but it doesn't look immediately tractable.

Comment: For $C = 0$ we get the special logistic solutions $(x(t), y(t)) = \left(\frac{3}{1 + D e^{-3 t}}, 0\right)$.